Examples for ApplicationModuleDetectionStrategy
I am looking at Spring Modulith and saw in the documentation that the modules detection strategy can be customised implementing the ApplicationModuleDetectionStrategy interface. Documentation stops there, though, and I haven't found examples around so I was wondering if anyone in this audience has already implemented it and, in that case, can post some examples on what to do within that interface implementation?
Thank you in advance,

This is a very late answer, but I saw your question whilst trying to figure this out myself, this is what I came up with (based on nesting my modules inside a package named 'module')
public class CustomApplicationModuleDetectionStrategy implements ApplicationModuleDetectionStrategy {
@Override
public Stream<JavaPackage> getModuleBasePackages(JavaPackage basePackage) {
    JavaPackage modulePackage = basePackage.getDirectSubPackages().stream()
            .filter(subPackage -> subPackage.getName().contains("module"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(basePackage);
    return modulePackage.getDirectSubPackages().stream();
}

}
